# How to update asp.net page asynchronously with a long web service

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my simulated process: a web service FindPrimeNumbers(int Num) will find a number of prime numbers equal to the input value.  For example, if  (Num = 1000), then FindPrimeNumber(1000) will find the first 1000 primes starting with 1, 2, 3 etc.  Whenever a prime number is found, it should update the web page by appending the new prime number to a label.

I am thinking to use .net web api as my service.  What I don't know is how to (raise an event?) update the web page whenever a prime is found.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Answer (score 0):

ajax wouldn't work here - it's either `success` or `error`. Think about it this way - if your web service was returning json and you flushed a partial response, it would end up looking like `{'test': 'fun`; it would be unparsable and of no use.

You'd need to use a WebSocket instead as LB mentioned. This will allow you to open a connection and raise events on the server and client side between the two as you please. Here's a [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets) with browsers that support. (currently Chrome/FF/Safari/IE10+)

Answer (score 0):

I have thought about something like this before, but I still don't have a chance to actually work on it. My suggestion is to have a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).
Somehow, you will execute a long-run function in the code behind. Then it will run and update client everytime there is new result until its done.